# Using yahoo_finance api in PySide Simple Application

Tags: python, pyside, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to do a system tray indicator for get the price of different companies. I'm using PySide for ui and yahoo_finance package for get data.

This code shows prices of two different companies:

```
import yahoo_finance
labels = ['SAN', 'IXD1.SG']
for x in labels:
    o = yahoo_finance.Share(x)
    print(o.get_price())
```

But, after call QApplication method, i get this error:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import yahoo_finance
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
labels = ['SAN', 'IXD1.SG']
for x in labels:
    o = yahoo_finance.Share(x)
    print(o.get_price())


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/yahoo_finance/__init__.py", line 23, in edt_to_utc
date_ = datetime.strptime(date.replace(" 0:", " 12:"), mask)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: pm
```

I've searching why this happened but i couldn't find any solution.

- I check locale settings before and after call QApplication, but everything is ok.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with PySide. What error do you get if you only run your first block of code ?

Comment: No errors. If you run the first code you'll get price of Santander and Inditex. I think maybe it's related to date formatting. Which steps may i try to find the problem?

Comment: So please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With the previous examples you can reproduce the error. I reduce the main app code trying to find the shortest way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see. I just tried with your second block of code, and I don't have any error. Maybe try to update yahoo_finance. Also, I'm on Linux OpenSuse.